# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

[image]
Getting below exeception for the line `pst_hldr`.

Also find the error below:

```
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/reditt/redit1.py", line 44, in get_links
    pst_hldr = wait.until(cond.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='QBfRw7Rj8UkxybFpX-USO']")))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

code:

```
def get_links(*keywords):
    urllist = []
    keystring = ''
    for kw in keywords:
        keystring += kw + "%20"
        keystring = keystring.strip()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")

    driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=' + keystring)
    driver.maximize_window()

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    tbody = wait.until(cond.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='_3ozFtOe6WpJEMUtxDOIvtU']//*[@class='q4a8asWOWdfdniAbgNhMh']")))
    tb_bar = tbody.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_3ozFtOe6WpJEMUtxDOIvtU']//*["
                                         "@class='q4a8asWOWdfdniAbgNhMh']//*[@class='M7VDHU4AdgCc6tHaZ-UUy']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tb_bar)
    print("end of bar")
    k = 0
    for i in range(200):
        newht = i * 500
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(newht) + ");")
        time.sleep(0.1)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    pst_hldr = wait.until(cond.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='QBfRw7Rj8UkxybFpX-USO']")))
    pst_tiles = pst_hldr.find_elements_by_xpath(
        ".//*[@class='_1poyrkZ7g36PawDueRza-J']//*[@class='_2XDITKxlj4y3M99thqyCsO']//*["
        "@class='_1Y6dfr4zLlrygH-FLmr8x-']")
    for tl in pst_tiles:
        ttl = tl.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='y8HYJ-y_lTUHkQIc1mdCq _2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE']//a")
        href = ttl.get_attribute('href')
        print(href)
    driver.close()

get_links('america', 'coronavirus', 'cases')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those classes looks dynamic in nature, try with below code :

you can use the below `css_selector` :

```
div[data-testid='search-results-subnav']+div
```

In code,

```
pst_hldr = wait.until(cond.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='search-results-subnav']+div")))
```

However, this exception

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

is common, when you use Explicit wait which is `WebDriverWait`.

so try to use

```
driver.find_element_by_css("div[data-testid='search-results-subnav']+div")
```

and see what is the exact error you are getting.

**Update 1 :**

```
div[class*='ListingLayout-outerContainer'] div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(3)
```

in code :-

```
pst_hldr = wait.until(cond.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='ListingLayout-outerContainer'] div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(3)")))
pst_tiles = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-click-id='body'] span")))
for title in pst_tiles:
    print(title.text)
```

**Update 2 :**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=america%20coronavirus%20cases%20")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
pst_hldr = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='ListingLayout-outerContainer'] div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(3)")))
pst_tiles = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-click-id='body']")))
for title in pst_tiles:
    print(title.get_attribute('href'))
```

**Output :**

> Timeline suggests a link between Alzheimers, Prion Disease & Covid-19
> Vaccines
> +2,089 New Cases = 1,243,932 Total Cases in PA; +16 New Deaths = 27,941 Total Deaths in PA Take me out of Latam ✈ is that a good bet?
> r/CoronavirusDownunder random daily discussion thread - 13 August,
> 2021 The New York parade reappears Asian-Americans gather downstairs
> to protest Yan Limeng spread rumors about the origin of the virus
> Florida becomes epicentre of America’s pandemic as coronavirus cases
> surge 50 per cent. 1 in 5 coronavirus cases nationally is found in
> Florida Pre-market brief
> +1,811 New Cases = 1,241,843 Total Cases in PA; +11 New Deaths = 27,925 Total Deaths in PA Florida becomes epicentre of America’s
> pandemic as coronavirus cases surge 50 per cent What A Day:
> Reconcilable BIFerences by Sarah Lazarus & Crooked Media (08/11/21)
> r/CoronavirusDownunder random daily discussion thread - 12 August,
> 2021 Hungarian nationalism is not the answer - Slow Boring More
> evidence suggests COVID-19 was in US by Christmas 2019 3 Major Reasons
> Why I am All in GME Pre-market brief Know anyone who is PRO MASK / VAX
> / LOCKDOWN?
> +2,076 New Cases = 1,240,032 Total Cases in PA; +11 New Deaths = 27,914 Total Deaths in PA What A Day: Cuom Over by Sarah Lazarus &
> Crooked Media (08/10/21) r/CoronavirusDownunder random daily
> discussion thread - 11 August, 2021 Democrats and their accomplices in
> the media are working overtime in Texas and Florida to create panic in
> an effort to pressure governors to give them back the power to
> reinstate mask mandates and lockdowns in their communities. More
> evidence suggests COVID-19 was in US by Christmas 2019
> +1,280 New Cases = 1,237,956 Total Cases in PA; +1 New Deaths = 27,903 Total Deaths in PA Even if we don't compare the value of animal lives
> to human lives, the Holocaust comparison is still valid. AMC Talks
> Bitcoin, GameStop With Its Reddit Followers -- 2nd Update
> (https://markets.qtrade.ca/news/story?t=iKXJizM-dSY,RB0cWxp8F57oYAx8Odv4T-UoxUxTcyQA&article=651d9d865e21f8f0#651d9d865e21f8f0)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: still getting same issue.

Comment: I see you are on this page https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=america&type=link, what exactly you wanna do ? I have updated a bit above, try to run and share the exception if you face any.

Comment: i m on this page https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=america%20coronavirus%20cases%20 i want to fetch href link of each tiles https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/p2vtzs/whats_considered_normal_in_europe_but_horrific_in/  like this

Comment: @pkk : can you try now with updated 1 code above ?

Comment: nothing is getting printed , code gets exited

Comment: No error i guess it is not going in for loop. getting exited before that

Comment: @pkk : try out the new updated code above, should work for you now.

Comment: actually i want to fetch the href links instead of texts. ex: please check the screenshot attached.

Comment: @pkk : you should get in now if you run the updated 2 code above. that needed a little tweak

Comment: no need of pst_hldr right ? as it is not being used anywhere ?

Comment: no, you can remove if you want, that is just for visibility

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. You are using `WebDriverWait`, which waits for a fixed time (which you give) for an element to be visible. If the element was not found within that time, this exception is thrown. It is a way to tell you: "Hey, the element did not appear in the time you set".

Read more about this exception here: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/timeoutexception-in-selenium